# Binary to list strange output

Tags: list, erlang, binary, format

I have following code:

```
file:write(FileId, Packet),
file:close(FileId),
{ok, FileId1} = file:open("tmp/" ++ integer_to_list(Summ), [read]),
A = file:read_file("tmp/" ++ integer_to_list(Summ)),
{_, B} = A,
io:format(binary_to_list(B));
```

In the end of function i see `io:format` B output. But if i make that:

```
file:write(FileId, Packet),
file:close(FileId),
{ok, FileId1} = file:open("tmp/" ++ integer_to_list(Summ), [read]),
A = file:read_file("tmp/" ++ integer_to_list(Summ)),
{_, B} = A,
S = binary_to_list(B),
io:format(S);

io:format nothing output. Why?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably not rely on the single-argument `io:format/1` function:

```
3> B="helo\n".  
"helo\n"
4> io:format(B).
helo
ok
5> C="~p".
"~p"
6> io:format(C).
** exception exit: {badarg,[{io,format,[<0.26.0>,"~p",[]]},
                            {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
                            {shell,exprs,6},
                            {shell,eval_exprs,6},
                            {shell,eval_loop,3}]}
     in function  io:o_request/3
```

If the argument contains any formatting requests, your `io:format` call may die. I would recommend using a format string such as [`~p~n` or `~w~n`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2):

```
1> C="~p".
"~p"
2> io:format("~p~n", [C]).
"~p"
ok
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work perfectly well here:

```
3> {ok, FileId1} = file:open("tmp/" ++ integer_to_list(Summ), [read]),
3> A = file:read_file("tmp/" ++ integer_to_list(Summ)),
3> {_, B} = A,
3> S = binary_to_list(B),
3> io:format(S).
1213
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `io:format/1` is a *format string* which must not include any formatting control sequences which require arguments. If this occurs an error is generated. To output raw printable characters use `io:put_chars/1`.